# how does $.post know what data to return?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, post

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way or not and unable to find what I'm after so if someone can point out my mistake or let me know if I'm going down the wrong road that'd be great.

I am trying to post form data to another file using `$.post('example.php',data1:foo,data2:bar})`. The example.php page contains an INSERT sql query.

After this is executed, and the example.php page inserts the posted data into the DB, how can I get either a pass/fail/ANYTHING returned?

I have tried various `$.post('..php',{data..},function(data){})` examples I've seen on here and other sites, but the success function seems to return no matter what, even if there are glaring problems in the INSERT statement.

Here is an example of my code:

```
//validate transaction form
  $("#frmTransaction").validate({
    submitHandler: function(element) { 
      hidePageMessages();
      var invnum = document.frmTransaction.invnum.value;
      var recnum = document.frmTransaction.recnum.value;
      var status = document.frmTransaction.status.value;
      $.post("tran_add.php",
      {
        invnum:invnum,
        recnum:recnum,
        status:status
      },
      function(data){
        my_function(data)
      }
      );
    },
    rules: {        
      description: "required",
      amount: "required",
      account: "required",
      category: "required",
      payee: "required"
    },
    errorClass:"errorinline",
    validClass:"valid"

  });

  function my_function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
```

so, if the sql statement in tran_add.php is executed succesfully, THEN and ONLY THEN do I want the my_function executed, which will display as 'pass' message to the user. Does tran_add.php need to do anything other than the sql statement, ie return success or something? Or again, am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions, smacks around the back of the head for missing something obvious etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post()` returns data based on the `data` you send to the `url`. On your `tran_add.php` you need conditions like:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT table (column1,column2) VALUES ('value1','value2')");
if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0){
  // now return your stuff
  echo json_encode(array('test' => 'worked', 'see' => 'now'));
}
```

To test you should change

```
function my_function(data){
  alert(data);
}
```

to

```
function my_function(data){
  // use firebug with console to see object
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: perfect! the json statement was the missing link which I was unsure of how to use, just getting to grips with jquery/json/ajax etc, have always done everythin with just php - LOTS of page reloads.... Now I can get the data I'm after to be returned, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

You should do, for example:

```
$mySqlInsertStatement = "insert statement"

If($mySqlInsertStatement) //to check for successful insert
   Echo 0
Else
   Echo 3
```

(Of course if statement is lower case,etc. )

Then in the success statement, you should say:

```
If(success == 0)
   //success
Else
   //not success
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Function.Use `$.each();`

```
  function(data){
       $.each(data,function(key,value){
           alert(key+""+value);
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to echo the successful result, and jquery will do the rest for you.

I'm not a really experienced professional, and I have no idea what is happening behind the scenes. In my mind, it goes like this:

When php echoes a successful result, jquery/ajax sees that something is posted in the webpage after execution of script, and understands that the message means success, and executes its success function. If execution stops prematurely, and nothing is echoed or execution 'dies' prematurely or error message is echoed in an else clause, then that means that there was an error in execution, and the success function will not be run.

Hopefully someone can explain better what happens behind the scenes.

Anyway, fact of the matter is if you echo a message like "Execution Successful" in your if clause at the end of the script, only then your js success function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the success function will be called as long as there is any response from the server that is not an error (HTTP Code 400/404/500/etc). So, you have two options:

1) have your php app Set an error if the insert is not successful:

```
<?php
http_response_code(502);
?>
```

2) have the php return some data that the success function can parse to know what happened (I recommend returning json if you can), something like:

```
{"result":"error" "details":"Database Insert failed..."}
```

Or

```
{"result":"success", "new_id":42}
```

My preference is to combine these approaches.